# Nothing happens when I call DialogBox()

Tags: c, winapi, dialog

I have an ancient C program (not C++ or C#) that needs to call the Win32 API `DialogBox()` function. But when I do that call, nothing happens - there's no dialog box, and the program just continues to the next step (which is calling `MessageBox()`).  I can't figure out why, although my guess is that one of the parameters is wrong - I just don't know how to fix it.

I'd show all the program here (and will if asked), but it is fairly verbose.  Instead, I'll show just the call that fails:

```
DialogBox(hInst,                       
          L"IDD_DIALOG1",  /*lpTemplate: name of Dialog Box Template*/
          hWnd,                       
          (DLGPROC) ControlKeyMenu);
```

My suspicion is that the problem is with the `lpTemplate` call; I've used the debugger to verify that the other 3 arguments all have non-NULL values at run-time.  `IDD_DIALOG1` is the name of a 'Dialog' in `MenuBox.rct`, which is one of the files in the project.  But there are a couple odd things:

1. When I modify the dialog box in `IDD_DIALOG1`, the calling code (the file that contains the above lines) doesn't re-compile.  But maybe dialog box changes don't require recompilation, they just get called at run-time?
2. If I change `IDD_DIALOG1` to some other string (like "foobar"), the run-time behavior is just the same - nothing happens.  So, apparently, a failure at this point doesn't result in a run-time error.

I've looked for online examples of code using `DialogBox()`, or just showing how to create an `lpTemplate` by hand, but the only ones I can find are C++, and I really don't want to convert this old-style C code to C++ just to get this dialog box working.  And it's not obvious to me how to convert C++ instructions to the corresponding C instructions.

I'm using Visual Studio 2022 for this, and one possibility is that the `MenuBox.rct` file is not really part of the project - it's listed as a file under the project name in the "Solution Explorer", but maybe there's something else I need to do in the code itself to link it in?

Similarly, I've got an old `resource.rc` file that could serve as the template for the dialog box, and it's listed in the "Solution Explorer", but edits to that file don't result in recompilation, so again I'm not sure if it's really part of the project.

Bottom line: How do I create and call an actual `lpTemplate` in C, and what is the proper way to "**include**" it (if that's the right word) in C code?

Comment: `IDD_DIALOG1` would normally be a symbol, not a literal string. Try `MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1)` instead.

Comment: Can you show the line in the resource script that defines the dialog? Also, just a quick rundown of how resource scripts work: They get compiled into a binary form using *rc.exe*. The output is then **linked** into the final executable. When you say the C code doesn't get recompiled after making changes to the resource script, then that is to be expected. The application should still get re-linked. Are you seeing a linker invocation after those changes?

Comment: @JonathanPotter:  According to the documentation for DialogBoxA (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-dialogboxa), the lpTemplate "is either the pointer to a null-terminated character string that specifies the name of the dialog box template or an integer value that specifies the resource identifier of the dialog box template. "  I don't know how to get the resource identifier, so I was going with the name.  And the name works, once you set up VS2022 right (see my answer).

Comment: @IInspectable: I don't know how to find the line in the script, since the MenuBox.rct file is "compiled"--it's built off of a visual dialog box editor, no script visible to me.  The line in my resource.rc file (which I eventually got working, see my answer) was `MenuBox DIALOGEX DISCARDABLE  0, 0, 177, 98`.  As for rc.exe, I don't know where that is--I did a linux `find` but it doesn't show up.  Looks like you can only get to it from inside the IDE.  Likewise for the linker, I don't see any output from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault: My resource.rc file was showing up under the "EXE" header in the "Solution Explorer", but not under the "Solution Items".  (In other words, my problem statement "one possibility is that the MenuBox.rct file is not really part of the project" was correct.)  Once I added it to the "Solution Items", I was able to refer to the contents (a DIALOGEX) from my executable.

I'm guessing I could also refer to the IDD_DIALOG1 by putting its parent file (the MenuBox.rct file) under "Solution Items" as well, although I haven't tried that.

No, I don't really understand this "Solution Explorer" thing, nor what goes where.  I'm afraid I pine for the old makefile way...sometimes these IDEs just make life harder, especially for us old guys.

Thanks to all who looked at this.

Comment: I'm glad you have got your solution and thank for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.